# Android NDK Native JPEG encoding

Tags: android-ndk, jpeg, encode, libjpeg

How can I encode an array of ARGB pixels into JPEG (jpg) file using the NDK in C? But not using any call to the Java API wrappers from it?
I saw there is a library call libjpeg, but I couldn't find any tutorial of how to use it in the NDK. Any more options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the tutorial for you please check this http://www.usefullcode.net/2011/01/android_ndklibjpeg.html open this link in google chrome or some other browser with google translator

Answer (score 1):

Besides JNI calls there are at least 2 options:

1) Use `libjpeg` directly. The source code can be downloaded here: http://www.ijg.org The source code is very NDK-friendly and you will just need to create `Android.mk/Application.mk` for the project. However, API of `libjpeg` is quite complicated.

2) Use a wrapper image library. I will recommend using `FreeImage`: http://freeimage.sourceforge.net  It has very clean API, can be easily compiled for Android (no autoconf configuration required) and is of production quality (used in Unity3D engine). As an additional bonus you will be able to read and write many other image formats, besides JPEG. Actually it contains `libjpeg`, but provides cleaner API.

Comment: Is there any example of how to compile libjpeg statically into my project?

Comment: Check out this tutorial for libjpeg: http://www.usefullcode.net/2011/01/android_ndklibjpeg.html

Answer (score 1):

Many years have passed since the above question was asked, and things have changed.

Since Android 11 (API level 30), there is an NDK-provided API for performing image conversions, both encoding (https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/bitmap) and decoding (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/image-decoder). JPEG encoding is covered by that API.